# Compare arrays in Ruby and print common elements

Tags: ruby

I want to compare two arrays in Ruby, and print any common elements. Using the imaginary "compare", I want:

```
arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
arr2 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]

arr1.compare(arr2) #=> [1, 3, 5]
```

or some other method which iterates over each element of `arr1` and tries to find a match with any element of `arr2`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hmmm... Not that I'm a judge, by why not use the [`Array#&`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-26) method?

> Set Intersection — Returns a new array containing elements common to the two arrays, excluding any duplicates. The order is preserved from the original array.

```
arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
arr2 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
arr1 & arr2 # => [1, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
arr2 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]

arr1.each do |x|
  if (arr2.include?(x))
    print "#{x} "
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Not elegant as Myst's solution, but it's worth to consider.

```
irb(main):001:0> arr1
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
irb(main):002:0> arr2
=> [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
irb(main):003:0> arr1.select{|x| arr2.include?(x)}
=> [1, 3, 5]
```

More efficient solution, after Cary Swoveland's comment.

```
irb(main):08:0> arr1.select{|x| arr2.to_enum.include?(x)}
=> [1, 3, 5]
```

Comment: This is relatively inefficient, as elements of `arr2` are repeatedly enumerated by `include?`. That could be addressed by converting `arr2` to a set `s2` and check if `s2.include?(x)`, as lookups are much faster with sets than with arrays, but I expect array intersection will be faster.

Comment: Thanks grandpa. I will use enums more frequently from now on :)  I just call methods on shell and iterate over randomly until if it is suitable to use in that context. Strictly speaking really don't know, what is happening behind the doors :)

Comment: Cool idea. I would also remove any found items from the lookup, to save on resources for each lookup... `require 'set'; arr2 = arr2.to_set; arr1.select{|x| arr2.delete?(x) } ` ... no need to repeat ourselves, is there? ;-)

Comment: my ruby returns `false` when i run this: `arr1.methods.include?('to_set')` is it implemented in new versions or what?

Comment: Your edit doesn't solve the problem addressed by @CarySwoveland - you are invoking `arr2.to_enum` on every iteration which is in fact *less* efficient. Furthermore, `to_enum` does not return a set.

Comment: Read about the Fruity gem, or Benchmark, and learn how to test the speed of your code. Extend the size of your arrays and benchmark your code against versions that use small arrays and long ones vs the selected answer. You will see why this solution is inefficient.